# How do I add the RequestExecutionLevel option of NSIS to a CMakeLists.txt

Tags: windows-7, cmake, nsis, cpack

I am trying to get an installer compiled with NSIS on Windows 7 to work without administrator privileges. The project is set up with CMake and compiled with VC2010. I have figured out that I have to use the

```
RequestExecutionLevel user
```

option. My question is: What do I have to put into my CMakeLists.txt to pass this option to NSIS? I found

```
set(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS "RequestExecutionLevel user")
```

somewhere on google, but that gives an error, saying that this option cannot be set in this section.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't know CMake, but in NSIS, RequestExecutionLevel is installer attribute (not valid in the section). So you can put it anywhere in your script except in a section or function. Is that it?

Answer (score 6):

The version of CMake that I have has `@CPACK_NSIS_DEFINES@` in NSIS template, so adding `set(CPACK_NSIS_DEFINES "RequestExecutionLevel user")` to CMakeLists.txt does the job as well.

Although [it may require extra work for component based install](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14522).

Answer (score 2):

You can try following steps:

1. Copy NSIS.template.in to your project directory, e.g. a subdirectory named "packaging":

   > `xcopy \cmake-install-path\modules\share\cmake-xxx\Modules\NSIS.template.in \your-project-directory\packaging\`
2. Add `RequestExecutionLevel user` to NSIS.template.in
3. Update CMAKE_MODULE_PATH in CMakeLists.txt:

   > `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/packaging)`

Then rebuild your package to see if it works.